# Permutation version of Ftest

Tags: permutation-test, f-test

is there some permutation test version of F-test (comparing equal variances of two data sets)?  I know the permutation version of T-test because I can shuffle data assuming to H0 (expected values are equal). I think that same variances don't imply that I can shuffle datas, or can I?

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous -- there are many F tests. Which *particular* F test do you mean? Please give the F test statistic.  What assumptions *can* you make in the nonparametric case? [Even if you can't do a distribution free test there may be a test that is nearly distribution free. On the other hand, while a test based on sample variances is a great way to compare population variances when you have normal distributions, it may be pretty inefficient in many other situations.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't shuffle values, because H0 does not assume the two distributions to have the same mean. You can shuffle deviations from the mean, because those are assumed to be equal under H0 (well, under some suitably chosen variant of H0 anyway).

Comment: How can I shuffle deviations from mean? I am not sure if I understand it. I have 2 datasets (X,Y), okay, now I can calculate means (mx,my). Next calculate all deviations : Xi- mx , Yi-my ( simple deviations or which one?) .. so now I have transformed original datas to 2 new datasets (A, B) with means 0 and same variance as original datasets (X,Y). Now I assume that A,B have equal means and same variances, so I can shuffle values from A,B and make som permutation test. Am I right?